# JS - custom "confirm" dialog

Tags: javascript, callback, popup, eval, confirm

I'm trying to replace the basic dialog box that pops out when using the `confirm` alert on JS. *(no jQuery)*
Basically I'm trying to launch a function that opens the popup, passing as an argument the command I want to be run. The command would then be added as a `onClick` function to the according button.

Here's a barebone example, where command can be something like `window.open('location')` or `function(par1,par2); function2(par1);` or simply `stuff.innerHTML = 'foo'`

```
function confirm(command) {
    openPopup();
    popup_button_close.onclick = function(){ closePopup(); };
    popup_button.onclick = function(){ command; closePopup(); };
}
```

Unfortunately the above example doesn't work, I guess because the string isn't being interpreted as actual code, and the popup closes without executing the command.

What would you suggest as the best approach to this? Would using `eval()` be a valid option?
Am I on the right path or should I reconsinder the whole thing with callbacks?
Because it's my understanding that, with callbacks, I'd need to hardcode every single response to the confirm button rather than dinamically pass it like I'm trying to do here, and that is not an option.

Comment: I would recommend making `command` a callback function, or adding another parameter for the callback. If `eval` is the solution, something is probably wrong.

Comment: Yeah I came to that conclusion as well and in fact `eval()` is the very last solution I will resort to in case any other option fails. Anyway, isn't turning `command` into a callback function making it a fixed function rather than the flexible solution I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Shouldn't, you could pass an anonymous function when you call it, `confirm(function() { /* do stuff */ });`.

Comment: Avoid window.open and use absolutely positioned div over the page content.

Comment: I can't avoid it, and I know it will cause problems with the callback, with the new window blocked.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I figured out that instead of passing a string, I had to pass a var containing the function.
The code now looks like this and works perfectly:

```
var command = new Function(string);
function confirm(command) {
    openPopup();
    popup_button_close.onclick = function(){ closePopup(); };
    popup_button.onclick = function(){ command(); closePopup(); };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might take advantage of `setTimeout()` accepting string as a complete statement:

```
function confirm(command) { // as a string "func(p1, p2, ...)"
    openPopup();
    popup_button.onclick = function(){
      setTimeout(command, 10);
    };
    closePopup();
}
```

This way you additionally benefit of reducing code since no event binding is needed for closing popup.